# Display textbox when image onclick

Tags: image, textbox, onclick, show

I want to display a textbox when user click on an image.

Here is my code :

```
 print "<img src=\"../resources/pictures/pages/edit-button.png\" height=\"18px\" onClick=\"document.getElementById('#$txtboxName').style.display=\"block\">";

 print "<input type=\"text\" name=\"$txtboxName\" size=\"20\" title=\"State Permission Here\" style=\"display:none\"    />";
```

My code wont work, any help?

Comment: Are you talking only about Javascript and HTML without referring to the server-side script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TKMjE/)

```
$('img').on('click',function(){
    $('#inputField').show();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace with getElementByName

```
 print "<img src=\"../resources/pictures/pages/edit-button.png\" height=\"18px\" onClick=\"document.getElementByName('#$txtboxName').style.display=\"block\">";

 print "<input type=\"text\" name=\"$txtboxName\" size=\"20\" title=\"State Permission Here\" style=\"display:none\"    />";
```